# Add first field as prefix to all other fields in line in a text file

Tags: linux, bash, text, awk

I'm hoping this might be solved easily with awk, though have not been able to manage it.

I have a tab separated multi-line text file. In each line there is an identifier in the first field, then between 0 and 8 additional fields with information about this identifier. Such as:

fileIhave.txt:

```
LOC107198162    GO:0016021                          
LOC107198170    GO:0004896   GO:0005515  GO:0016020                 
LOC107198182    GO:0016787                          
LOC107198203                                
LOC107198204    GO:0007160          
...
```

I have a need to add/copy the identifier (LOC*) to each of the fields in its respective line that include text (GO:*) and to add an "=" sign in between with spaces either side . i.e.

fileIwant.txt

```
LOC107198162    LOC107198162 = GO:0016021                           
LOC107198170    LOC107198170 = GO:0004896    LOC107198170 = GO:0005515   LOC107198170 = GO:0016020                  
LOC107198182    LOC107198182 = GO:0016787                           
LOC107198203                                
LOC107198204    LOC107198204 = GO:0007160   
...
```

I can kind of do this for the second field (first occurrence of information) by  using `awk 'BEGIN{OFS="\t"}$2=$1" = "$2'` but cannot seem to find the right way to apply to additional text fields in the line. Also, I don't want to copy the identifier to a field if there is no text there.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this awk script:

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) $i=$1 " = " $i}1' OFS='\t' fileIhave.txt
```

The script loops through all fields (except the first one) from the line and add the first field to all of them.

Comment: Thanks oliv, your solution has the same result as Kent above in adding the identifier on its own in an additional field at the end of each line. If this can be prevented it will be perfect.

Comment: @DanPowell I don't get your point. Please update the expected output in your question (to show the difference).

Comment: @DanPowell base on your comment on Kent's answer, are you looking for something like this: `awk '{end=NF+1;for(i=2;i<=end;i++) $i=$1 " = " $i}1' OFS='\t' fileIhave.txt` ?

Comment: thanks oliv, your original solution worked perfectly also as soon as i removed all the hidden characters in my file.

Comment: @DanPowell I'm glad to help. Please consider upvoting/accepting this answer if you find it useful.

Answer (score 1):

This one-liner should work:

```
awk '{OFS="\t" $1" = ";$1=$1}7' file
```

test with your example data (using gawk):

```
kent$  awk '{OFS="\t" $1" = ";$1=$1}7 ' f
LOC107198162    LOC107198162 = GO:0016021
LOC107198170    LOC107198170 = GO:0004896       LOC107198170 = GO:0005515       LOC107198170 = GO:0016020
LOC107198182    LOC107198182 = GO:0016787
LOC107198203
LOC107198204    LOC107198204 = GO:0007160
```

Comment: Excellent, thanks Kent.  It adds the prefix in every case though, seems to add an additional prefix on its own at the end of each line. Is there a way to prevent this?

Comment: @DanPowell The answer is based on your example data in question. If your input is different from the example, it may have the different result. I cannot see your input so I cannot tell how comes the result and how to fix.

Comment: Apologies, i should have reposted the output:            LOC107198162 LOC107198162 = GO:0016021 LOC107198162 = 
LOC107198170 LOC107198170 = GO:0004896 LOC107198170 = GO:0005515 LOC107198170 = GO:0016020 LOC107198170 = 
LOC107198182 LOC107198182 = GO:0016787 LOC107198182 = 
LOC107198203 LOC107198203 = 
LOC107198204 LOC107198204 = GO:0007160 LOC107198204 =

Comment: @DanPowell your real file must be different from the example you gave in question. there might be some in-visible chars in the file. make sure they are same, otherwise, it is hard for us to help you to solve the problem.

Comment: Kent you're exactly right, there are invisible characters. Apologies to you and @oliv and thanks.